# jQuery Validate require_from_group not allowing form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have two Boostrap form elements that I am trying to validate with at least 1 required:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Notification Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control notifGroup" id="notifEmail" name="notifEmail" />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="phone">Notification Phone Number for SMS:</label>
   <input type="text" class="input-medium bfh-phone notifGroup" data-country="US" id="notifPhone" name="notifPhone" />
 </div>
```

I have my scripts:

```
         <script src="/public/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
         <script src="/public/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
         <script src="/public/js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery validate version 1.15.0

and my validate function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#form').validate({

     rules: {
        notifPhone: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".notifGroup"]
        },
        notifEmail: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".notifGroup"]
        }  
    },
    messages: {


    },
     submitHandler: function(form) {


        var email = $('#notifEmail').val()
        var phone = $('#notifPhone').val()

        data = {

            phone,
            email
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://myurl/myendpoint',
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                if (res == true) {                  
                    $('#error').html('<p><strong>all good.</strong></p>')
                    $('#form')[0].reset()
                    $('#submitBtn').hide()
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#error').html('<p></p>')
                    }, 5000)
                }else if (res == 'over limit'){
                    $('#error').html('<p><strong>too many.</strong></p>');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#error').html('<p></p>')
                    }, 5000)                  
                }else {             
                    $('#error').html('<p><strong>already there.</strong></p>');
                    $('#form')[0].reset();
                    $('#submitBtn').hide()
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#error').html('<p></p>')
                    }, 5000)


                }

            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            },
            timeOut: 5000

        });

        return false;
    }

});
```

});

Everything worked fine until a decision was made to only require 1 of email or phone number. When both were required under straight forward validation there were no problems.

However now when trying to have only one required, no errors are thrown and the form just submits with blank values. If I put bad data in for one or both of the selectors instead of .notifGroup, the error is thrown on the field with the proper selector (or both with bad data) but the form won't submit even with both fields filled.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have commented my code and copied the code from Sparky's working JSFiddle into my project and it still will not work. Could there be a dependancy that I'm missing or possibly an order to my JS scripts that's wrong? It goes jQuery-jQValidate-additionalmethods-bootstrap-myajaxfile-myformvalidation-bootstrapformhelpers?

Comment: @Sparky, The error messages only show up if I have an incorrect or no selector in the rules. But obviously the form won't submit.

Comment: Did you follow my last comment about using the plugin's debugging option?

Comment: Yes I still get no errors in the console.

Comment: It's crazy because there has to be a difference somewhere as your fiddle works. But for the life of me I can't figure out what the issue could be since your code doesn't work in my project with all my code commented.

Comment: When using the `debug:true` option, you would not get "errors" in the console.  You would have to look at the console's "Log" section.  Regardless, whatever the issue, we cannot help if we cannot see it, as the posted code is indeed working in the jsFiddle.

Comment: I understand and believe me it is quite frustrating and I appreciate the time you are taking to help. my console logs have no errors.
Navigated to http://myurl/endpoint
my-ajax.js:104 true
Navigated to http://myurl/endpoint2

The true is just a bool being thrown in my code for something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$().ready(function() {...` is "not recommended" [as per jQuery `ready` handler documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Use `$(document).ready(function() {...` or `$(function() {...`
2. There is no reason to have a separate `.submit()` handler.  Use the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` for your ajax.  Your `.submit()` handler will likely interfere with the plugin, and [as per plugin documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler), the `submitHandler` callback is *"The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"*.
3. <s>The issue that seems to be causing your whole problem is:  `messages` is supposed to be a sibling of `rules`; you've incorrectly put a stray `}` inside of the `messages` object, which is causing a syntax error (*this should have been shown in your JavaScript console*).</s>

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pezez5um/**

---

**EDIT:**
If item #3 was only a typo in the OP, then item #2 was the likely culprit.

Comment: actually that was an error in deleting unnecessary data I will edit now.

Comment: @R.Erickson, regardless, then item #2 was the root cause of your issue.  Your `.submit()` handler is competing with the plugin's built-in capture of the same event.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The errant } was actually an error in deleting unnecessary data I will edit now. So I should switch the validation call and the submit call and replace the submit() with a submitHandler instead?

Comment: @R.Erickson, yes... see the code in my jsFiddle demo.  Ajax belongs inside the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.

Comment: made those changes however the form still submits without validating the fields. I get the alert but no validation.

Comment: I have even commented everything but the rules, the submitHandler and the alert and still no validation just the alert of success.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form').validate({
        
         rules: {
            notifPhone: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".notifGroup"]
            },
            notifEmail: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".notifGroup"]
            }  
        },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
            
            alert('valid - submitted with ajax');
            return false
        }
        
    });
});

Comment: Very confused. I see your fiddle working and I have the same code in my files however still no validation just form submit.

Comment: Just had a second set of eyes go over it. Going to try turning it off and turning it on again. At this point that's what I'm left with. haha

Comment: Check your console for JavaScript errors.  Certainly, there's a difference someplace... after all, my jsFiddle was constructed using the code from your OP.

Comment: If I change the selector name to something incorrect like 'x' instead of notifGroup, the errors are thrown but I can't submit.

Comment: No JS errors in console. Or any errors for that matter. Can't comment anymore but setting debug to true still nothing in the log.

Comment: Set `debug` option to `true` and look at the console log.